# Ruby, query model with aggregate with model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, aggregate-functions

In my rails application, at some point, I query my model simply. I want to query customers order information like how many orders were given by this customer within three months.

Just now, I query the model in that way:

```
@customer = Customer.all
```

*customer.rb*

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  audited
  has_many :orders
end
```

And customer may have orders.

*order.rb*

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  audited
  belongs_to :customer
end
```

What I would like to do is to query customers model and to inject aggregate function result to every customer records.

## EDİT

I tried to simulate every solution but couln't achieve.

I have the following query in mysql.

How do I need to code in ruby with activerecord to create that query ?

```
SELECT 
(SELECT 
        COUNT(*)
    FROM
        orders o
    WHERE
        o.customer_id = c.id
            AND startTime BETWEEN '2017.12.04' AND '2018.01.04') AS count_last_month,
(SELECT 
        COUNT(*)
    FROM
        orders o
    WHERE
        o.customer_id = c.id
            AND startTime BETWEEN '2017.10.04' AND '2018.01.04') AS count_last_three_month,
    c.*
FROM
customers c;
```

How can I achieve that?

Thanks.

Comment: You should use group by

Comment: Can you try this query `Customer.joins(:orders).group("orders.customer_id").where('created_at > ? and created_at < ?', Date.today - 3.months, Date.today).order("count(orders.customer_id) desc")`

Comment: @Hilmi Yamci, Are you looking for particular customer's order count  within 3 months?

Comment: Yes actually, I'm using pagin when I query customer, in that case, I want to aggregate only those customers orders counts

Comment: @HilmiYamcı, I have answered so please have a look.

Comment: I have just looked, I think it didn't help me. Actually, I will add another comment to the question just now. Can you look at it please ?

Comment: Answering your question stated in “edit”: there should be 2 different queries, both like shown in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
Customer.
  joins(:orders).
  group('customers.id').
  where('orders.created_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)')
  select('sum(orders.id), customers.*')
```

Comment: typo, should be `customers.id` also `where clause` to account for orders ordered from now till `3.months.ago`

Comment: @TheMouseMan thanks, fixed and added a where (I did not notice it in the OP.)

Answer (score -1):

As my understanding of you question. I have this solution for you question. Please have a look and try it once. In below query, 'includes' used to solve N+1 problem.

```
Customer.includes(:orders).where('created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?', Time.now.beginning_of_day, Time.now.beginning_of_day-3.months).group_by{|c|c.orders.count}
```

If you are looking for particular customer's order count then you can try this one.

```
@customer.orders.where('created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?', Time.now.beginning_of_day, Time.now.beginning_of_day-3.months).group_by{|c|c.orders.count}
```

Comment: This is plain old good ruby `Enumerable#group_by`, hence `N+1`. Downvoted.

Comment: @mudasobwa, Can you tell me what Hilmi Yamcı want here?

Comment: I believe they want to get this result _avoiding_ a penalty of [`N+1 query`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-n1-select-query-issue).